# Why does my Mercurial HG repo grow substantially when renaming files?

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo which counted 50,1 MB as Windows Explorer presents it when I checked properites of the `.hg` folder. Then I renamed a folder containing 341 files and 4MB, checked in the changes, and the repo now counted 54,5MB. I used the following command to rename:

```
hg rename -vf oldFolder newFolder
```

What's wrong? I'm only changing references, not cloning files here, am I not?

edit: Any tips on how I can debug this is also appreciated.

Comment: Nothing wrong. A version control (like the name suggests) persists the entire history. Therefore even changes that seem not to contain any data, increase data in the cumulative database. You would see the same effect with any version control system.

Comment: I just did a test with git, and that was not the case there. Repo size before: 7.37MB, repo size after rename: 7.29MB (Don't ask me how it *shrunk*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't store renames efficiently right now.

When files are initially stored, their entire contents is put in the repository (obviously). Later modifications only take up the space of the diff (with some compression applied).

However, the storage is done using a so-called '[revlog](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Revlog)'. This revlog stores all versions of a file. Renaming will create a new revlog, where again an 'initial storage' takes up the size of an entire file, instead of a diff.

This is not an inherent problem (so most likely it will be solved 'eventually'), but it's quite complex to solve in a nice way. See [this bug](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883) for more details.

Git stores files in a different way, which handles renames without this overhead. That's why you don't see any growth. The 'shrinking' you see most likely has to do with [garbage collection](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of the `hg rename` command:

```
hg rename [OPTION]... SOURCE... DEST

aliases: move, mv

rename files; equivalent of copy + remove

    Mark dest as copies of sources; mark sources for deletion. If dest is a
    directory, copies are put in that directory. If dest is a file, there can
    only be one source.
```

As documented, the rename command is the equivalent of a copy, and then a remove, and a record of where the file was copied from.